# How to store meta data in a SQL Server database to differentiate it from other databases?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, metadata

I have a scenario where I need to show from many databases only a certain kind of database, this is done by querying to see if the database has 4 tables:

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 4 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
FROM SYS.TABLES
WHERE UPPER(NAME) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

If it returns true its the correct db and it should show in the list. My question is, what other alternatives are there for storing some sort of meta data that I could access as a developer, say from C# to decide more quickly (instead of querying every single db) and accurately (someone might add those tables) if its a correct database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server objects have all got extended properties associated with them for this purpose. You can set extended properties. This is covered in this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx.

```
sp_addextendedproperty @name='IsOfInterestToMe', @value=1
```

will create an extended property of that name and value on your current database.